# Received offer letter directly from company, haven't talked to recruiter yet, should I still talk to the recruiter?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, recruitment

So I got in touch with a company through a recruiter. The recruiter told me via email that I should call them back immediately after the interview so they can speak on my behalf, negotiate salary and ensure I am still a candidate. The interview was today. I was in a rush to get back to my current company that I forgot to call. I just received an offer letter directly from the company. The offer letter gives me everything I wanted. Should I still call the recruiter? I'm not sure what the correct protocol is in this situation.

I'm just worried that the company won't like it if I inform the recruiter. They might have been trying to go behind the recruiter's back.

Comment: Did you get the offer via e-mail (same day "letter" seems to indicate so...)? If so, reply to company via e-mail and CC recruiter.

Comment: @MaxW Yes, it was a pdf attachment to an email.

Comment: @MaxW I'm worried that the company won't like that (i.e. they were trying to go behind the recruiter's back). I know that the recruiter gets a certain share of the agreed salary.

Comment: You stated that you got contact with company from the recruiter. You want to keep a good rapport  with recruiter. You may be looking for a job in the future and the recruiter will be able to help you. Above all you want to act ethically in front of the company. If they are trying to go behind the recruiter's back then the company's HR is acting unethically -- and they (the HR contact) know it.

Comment: @MaxW OK thanks. Should I also make a phone call to the recruiter or is an email with CC to the recruiter adequate?

Comment: @MaxW I just realized that the company CCed the recruiter so this has all been for naught haha. Should have paid more attention. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Anon oops, wrote my answer while you were typing your comment.. nevermind my answer

Comment: I guess a last thought is that before accepting is there something in particular for which the recruiter may be able to sweeten the deal? So no harm in talking to recruiter about that before accepting. Remember that the recruiters save the company a lot of work if they have screened out bad candidates.  So the company should want to maintain a good relationship with recruiter too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would play it lightly. Answer the offer email first to them only.

After you send another email to the recruiter alone to tell him thanks for the contact, as you have accepted their offer, for a great place it look like, etc.. (and that you didn't needed to contact him afterhand, because they offered you what you wanted). In any case if the recruiter forward your email to the HR to negotiate something, you will not look bad at all.